# CheckBox replace setOnCheckedChangeListener with setOnLongClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, onlongclicklistener

I have a CheckBox that I need to respond to OnLongClickListener **instead** of OnCheckedChangeListener. How do I do that? Right now even though I implement the OnLongClickListener, the CheckBox still toggles when a user clicks it. I want the toggle to happen on longClick only as in

```
checkBox.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
            ...
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two things...

Not sure if they will work. I did not tested.

Maybe you can disable the click on layout file. Enable only the long click.

```
  <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:longClickable="true"
        ..... />
```

Or, you can override onCheckedChangeListener to do not take any action.

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        checkBox.setChecked(!isChecked);
    }
});
```